# Can't mount partition/partitions not recognized in Solaris 11.1

Tags: mount, partition, solaris, gparted, parted

I'm playing around with Solaris 11.1, and have run into a bit of a problem...

I've installed three OS on my computer - LinuxMint, FreeBSD and Solaris - and have partitioned my harddrive (/dev/sda on LinuxMint) thus:

Disk 500GB

- sda1 (Primary Partition): FreeBSD (UFS) 50GB
- sda2 (PP): "Storage" (VFAT) 50GB
- sda3 (PP): Solaris (zpool/zfs) 100GB
- sda4 Extended Partition (what's left)

  - sda5 (Logical Partition): LinuxMint, / (root) 50GB
  - sda6 (LP): LinuxMint, /home 100GB
  - sda7 (LP): LinuxMint, swap 2.5GB

I used LinuxMint `fdisk` to set-up the partitions, using "old-style" DOS partition-table.  I boot with `grub` in MBR, managed from LinuxMint.  In addition, the Solaris-partition has it's own GRUB (to select between Solaris boot-enviroment) - it shows when I select "Solaris" from the MBR-GRUB.

In LinuxMint, all partitions are correctly identified and listed - and accessable.  When I used `gparted` from LinuxMint, the disk is shown as partitioned as described above.

However in Solaris, it doesn't look like all partitions are correctly identified - in fact, I seem to only be able to access the Solaris-one... and it's sort of reported as being the only partiton on the disk (I think):

```
# zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool     ONLINE       0     0     0
      c7d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I've not used Solaris much - and I still struggle with how it addresses disk-partitions - but in my mind, c7d0**s0** means "controller: 7, disk: 0 and slice(?) 0" - I would've expected slice 2 or 3, since it's the 3rd partition on the disk.

When I use `gparted` (as *root*) under Solaris, my harddisk (/dev/sdk/c7d0**p0**) is reported as being one large block of "unalocated" with a size of 500GB - this matches the size of my disk...  But since I'm working from it, I know there is *at least* a 100GB zpool there with several zfs filesystems.

Probably it's just me not knowing the ins and outs of Solaris enough - or how what commands to use - but I'm stomped...

What I would like to do, is mount the VFAT-partiton (/dev/sda2 under LinuxMint) under Solaris.  As I understand it, Solaris is able to read VFAT-partitions (unlike for example ext4), and I'd like to use it to back-up some stuff from Solaris...

So how do I get Solaris to "see" the other partitions on the disk?  What should be the device of the 2nd partition on the disk?  I assume the `mount` command works pretty much like the one in Linux...

Comment: `zpool` is for ZFS only, `df` should print things better.  No clue why `gparted` is going mad though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actually happens with Solaris is that when you create a partition, Solaris will create a "disk" inside it. So when you see c7d0s0, means controller 7 disk 0 slice 0. Now in x86 the disk is in fact your partition.
Your full disk contains something along these lines:
Physical disk:

- sda1 - Linux
- sda2 - VFAT partition
- sda3 - Solaris partition with SMI label.

  - Slice 0 thourgh slice 8, slice 2 represents the full disk (x86 partition)
- sda4

  - sda5
  - sda6
  - sda7

Traditionally if you want to mount the VFAT partition, you can do it like this:

```
mount -F pcfs /dev/dsk/c7d0p1 /path/to/mountpoint
```

if you want to see which partition have recognized filesystems, you can also do:

```
fstyp /dev/rdsk/c7d0p1 or p2 or p3
```

In addittion, you can do fdisk /dev/rdsk/c1t0p0 to list all the partitions, careful not to use destroying options.

You can also take a look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/pradhap/entry/mount_ntfs_ext2_ext3_in) for more information.

Comment: Yes, that worked just fine!  Thank you so very much for explaining this.